# How to unlock a folder

Tags: security

I want to install a new theme to Plank but the folder is locked and I have no idea how to unlock it. Super new to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in Files? If so, that sounds like you need to open Files by right-clicking on it and selecting "Run as Administrator," or something to that effect (I'm not on my elementary machine right now.).
Then try opening the file.
On a side note: if it's a theme, and it's in the proper folder, can you just change the theme by ctrl+right-clicking on plank and changing the theme in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

To modify a system or locked folder in Elementary OS or linux, open Terminal (Window + T or Command + T) and simply use this two commands below: (run one command each times)

```
sudo su 
chmod -R go+rw /path/folder name
```

Example: `chmod -R go+rw /opt/lampp`

Comment: Thank you for conttibuting to the elementay OS Stack Exchange. Reading the question, we must asume Cayden is refering to the inablility to ad files to `/usr/share/plank/themes`. Using your solution, although tehnically correct, would also result in changing the permissions to a 'system' folder, and that is strongly discouraged. In Cayden's specific situation it is strogly recommened to simply copy the new theme in `~/.local/share/plank/themes`. This way, permissions remain untouched, and the new theme might be preserved in case of a system reinstallation (assuming /home is backed up)